# How to load data in pre-controller and pass directly to view in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, codeigniter, laravel-5.1

I am developing a Laravel 5 project. That is an e-commerce project. I want to load all categories for every request. Because that are used in navigation bar. Before I was using Codeigniter Framework. In CodeIgniter, I did like this. I created a Controller class named "MainController" that extends CI_Controller.

So the class details is like:

```
class MainController extends CI_Controller{

public $data;

function __construct()
{
    $this->data["categories"] = getCategries();
}

}
```

Then every controller extends MainController and pass data to view like this.

```
class Home extends MainContoller{

 function index(){
  $this->load->view('view',$this->data);
 }

}
```

I tried a similar way in Laravel. But data property values are not included when it reached to the child controller. So I tried to use Middleware. Then tried to pass the data together with request to the controller. But controller is still having to do something like this

```
   $data['categories'] = $request->categories;
```

I will need to do it in every action. I do not like it. How can I achieve it like in CodeIgniter? I am currently using Laravel 5.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [view composer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/views#view-composers).

If you are not familiar with concepts like that I recommend to read the entire linked tutorial page.